# Updating float4 declaration from dx9 to dx11

Tags: directx, shader

There's a shader which was given which I'm trying to update to be compatible with the newest Unity 5 (presumably dx11).  I don't understand how float4 basic instantiation from dx9 was working.  Can someone help me understand the following syntax and then provide an equivalent dx11 syntax?

I understand that float4 normally uses x,y,z,w or xyz,y as arguments, but what does did a single float argument do?  Did float4(0.01) make {.01,0,0,0} or does float4(.01) make {.01,.01,.01,.01}?

Original code from the shader:

```
float4 Multiply19 = float4( 0.01 ) * float4( 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should make a new float4 with all members (xyzw) set to 0.01 and then multiply all that by 0, effectively making Multiply19 a (0, 0, 0, 0) float4.